# Entity Framework Overkill?

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, orm

So I have a project and we have some data access requirements. This is fairly simple, we just want to retrieve data returned from a stored procedure (this already exists) and update a couple of tables. My options I guess are to:

- Write a bespoke Data Access component that could be used on other projects as well
- Use Microsoft's Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block - however, as the source is Oracle and would want to use ODP this may also need to use the Enterprise Library Contrib?
- Use an ORM such as Entity Framework
- Other alternatives?

I am leaning towards option 2, although it seems I would also need to use the Contrib? I am thinking there isn't much benefit of using the Entity Framework for a fairly simple solution such as this, particularly when having to integrate with SPs?

Or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put serious thought to using a micro-ORM such as dapper, massive, Simple.Data, peta-poco etc. this makes it easy to call the procs and process the grids, without the complexity and overhead of a full ORM. I know dapper works with both oracle and procs.

Comment: Why not simply use the Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block?

Comment: @Jon because I've used it before ;p it is a bit awkward, and frankly doesn't add much over just using ADO.NET directly. dapper, on the other hand, *does* - i.e. handling all parameterisation and materialisation for you *trivially*.

Comment: The problem would be introducing another ORM when we are trying to standardise as much as possible.

Comment: @Jon well, you *did* say, and I quote, "Other alternatives?", and re EF you did say "such as". If you can't use it, fine. But note - it *isn't* a (full) ORM - it is just a **very friendly** (and fast) wrapper around ADO.NET. Heck, it is one file ;p

Comment: OK, I will check it out and I agree I was looking for other alternatives. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

is the stored procedure and tables all in the same oracle db? If so why not just write a bit of pl/sql?

Comment: There will be PL SQL but at the .NET level I want to make it easier to make calls to the Oracle dB, rather than the repetitive code in ODP. Plus I would like a layer of abstraction on-top of the physical database.

Comment: @Jon I don't know your app but it does seem like overkill a bit, I would have to ask why you want a layer of abstraction over the db? Whats wrong with using the db - the question I'd ask is how long would it take to pop in a procedure vs how long would it take to add an alternative, and are there benefits. If there's other reasons then fine, but for your stated problem I'd find it very hard to justify another solution when it would take a couple of hours to pop in a pl/sql block

Comment: Even with an SP you still need to write code in .NET to perform the data access and this can be cumbersome. Using something like the Microsoft's Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block or an ORM can shelter you from this and increase productivity moving forward.

Comment: @Jon in your question you said you were only doing this once - to introduce an entire new library to update a couple of tables seems overkill, I suspect there is something else you're trying to do.

Comment: Ah OK, I can see this could be a little misleading, apologies. It is likely to be more than one operation that needs to be performed. However, still not a huge amount.